# how I can send a instruction to the VM virtualbox with subprocess.call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, virtualbox

I have a VM in virtualbox, with python I can start the machine with

```
subprocess.call(["C:\...\VBoxManage.exe", "startvm", "my_vm"])
```

How I can run know the abc.exe, located on the desktop?
With the instruction below it's not possible..

```
subprocess.call(["C:\...\VBoxManage.exe", "guestcontrol", "my_vm", "run C:\\Users\\abc.exe"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run` is a keyword argument so set it as separate item in the list.

```
subprocess.call(["C:\...\VBoxManage.exe", "guestcontrol", "my_vm", "run", "C:\\Users\\abc.exe"])
```

On second review at the Virtualbox docs, it quotes:

> run [common-options]
>   [--exe <path to executable>] [--timeout ]
>   [-E|--putenv [=]] [--unquoted-args]
>   [--ignore-operhaned-processes] [--no-profile]
>   [--no-wait-stdout|--wait-stdout] [--no-wait-stderr|--wait-stderr]
>   [--dos2unix] [--unix2dos]
>   -- <program/arg0> [argument1] ... [argumentN]]

See the `--` argument before `<program/arg0>`. Usually to accept arguments after that as literal and looks required, so also try:

```
 subprocess.call(["C:\...\VBoxManage.exe", "guestcontrol", "my_vm", "run", "--", "C:\\Users\\abc.exe"])
```